# Singleton handler for reading and writing configuration.json

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a current project of I have multiple modules that need to read from and write to a `config.json` file, where the settings are saved as nested dictionaries. I chose `json` here, because I want the config file to be human-readable.

**Simplified example config.json:**

```
{
  "server_data": {
    "email_address": "something@somewhere.com",
    "server_address": "imap.server.com",
    "server_port": 993
  },
  "handle_emails": {
    "output_directory": "C:\\Users\\riskypenguin\\some_directory",
    "mark_read": false,
    "write_to_file": true,
    "folders": ["inbox"]
  },
  "output": {
    "output_directory": "C:\\Users\\riskypenguin\\some_other_directory",
    "print_timeinfo": true,
    "print_form_counts": true
  }
}
```

---

My `config_handler.py` provides standardised access to the file via `get_setting` and `set_setting`. For different use cases throughout the project I need to be able to access the configuration settings at varying depths. For example: Some `boolean` settings are read and written directly, but the `dict` at `server_data` will be read and processed as a whole. Concurrency is not relevant for this project, so there are no collisions regarding read and write access.

**config_handler.py**

```
import os
import json
from functools import reduce

from definitions import CONFIG_DIR, CONFIG_FILE, DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE

__all__ = ["get_setting", "set_setting"]


# Helper functions

def _save_config_data(content):
    if not os.path.exists(CONFIG_DIR):
        os.makedirs(CONFIG_DIR)

    with open(CONFIG_FILE, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(obj=content, fp=f, indent=2)


def _load_config_data():
    file = CONFIG_FILE if os.path.exists(CONFIG_FILE) else DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)


_config_data = _load_config_data()


# Exported functions

# Old version of get_setting, currently not in use
def get_setting_old(*args, default=None):
    current_value = _config_data

    for key in args:
        if isinstance(current_value, dict):
            current_value = current_value.get(key, default)
        else:
            return default

    return current_value


def get_setting(*config_keys, default=None):
    drill_down = lambda x, y: dict.get(x, y, default) if isinstance(x, dict) else default
    return reduce(drill_down, config_keys, _config_data)


def set_setting(*config_keys, value):
    current_value = _config_data

    for key in config_keys[:-1]:
        if isinstance(current_value, dict):
            current_value = current_value.get(key)
        else:
            return False

    last_key = config_keys[-1]
    if isinstance(current_value, dict):
        current_value[last_key] = value
    else:
        return False

    _save_config_data(_config_data)

    return True
```

---

As this is my first shot at handling configurations in a central way like this I am grateful for all feedback. I'm particularly interested in feedback about:

1. General approach
2. Comparison between the haskell-like approach of `get_setting` vs. the simpler and more readable approach of `get_setting_old`
3. `set_setting` seems rather unelegant to me. As the types of a setting can be either mutable or immutable I don't see a better solution though. I've thought about wrapper classes for primitive types, but that feels rather unpythonic and creates some unnecessary overhead when reading from and before writing to `json`. Maybe I'm missing something here.
4. I've been thinking about creating a simple class for a path of config_keys, to be able to pass a ConfigKeyPath object instead of a bunch of separated string arguments. I'm not sure which of the two approaches is better.

Comment: Why are you only allowed to get items from dictionaries? Why are lists on anything else that implements `__getitem__` not allowed?

Comment: The short answer is that I hadn't thought of that up until now. I guess my current approach is: Anything that is not a dict marks the lowest level of a setting. Any further handling needs to be done by the code that retrieves the setting. Refactoring `get_setting` it to use `__getitem__` instead of `dict.get` should be easy enough though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rather than `os` and `os.path` use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths).

   ```py
   def _save_config_data(content):
       CONFIG.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
       with open(CONFIG, 'w') as f:
           json.dump(obj=content, fp=f, indent=2)


   def _load_config_data():
       file = CONFIG if CONFIG.exists() else DEFAULT_CONFIG
       with open(file, 'r') as f:
           return json.load(f)
   ```
2. Your code doesn't follow idiomatic Python.
   Python uses errors for control flow so returning `True`/`False` in `set_setting` is not idiomatic.
3. You should make a `walk` function which you call from both `get_setting` and `set_setting`.
4. [Reduce is generally not a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/181543).
   I would say in the specific example of your code, `get_setting_old` has far superior readability to `get_setting`.

```py
import os
import json
from functools import reduce

from definitions import CONFIG, DEFAULT_CONFIG

__all__ = [
    "get_setting",
    "set_setting",
]


# Helper functions

def _save_config_data(content):
    CONFIG.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(CONFIG, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(obj=content, fp=f, indent=2)


def _load_config_data():
    file = CONFIG if CONFIG.exists() else DEFAULT_CONFIG
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)


def _walk(obj, path):
    for segment in path:
        obj = obj[segment]
    return obj


def get_setting(*args, default=_SENTINEL):
    try:
        return _walk(_CONFIG_DATA, args)
    except LookupError:
        if default is _SENTINEL:
            raise LookupError(f"cannot walk path; {args}") from None
        else:
            return default


def set_setting(value, *args):
    *args, segment = args
    try:
        node = _walk(_CONFIG_DATA, args)
        node[segment] = value
    except LookupError:
        raise LookupError(f"cannot set path; {args}") from None


_SENTINEL = object()
_CONFIG_DATA = _load_config_data()
```

5. I think using a class would be better as then you can define `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` for a potentially nicer interface.

```py
class Walker:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        
    def __getitem__(self, args):
        if not isinstance(args, tuple):
            args = (args,)
        return self.get(*args)

    def __setitem__(self, args, value):
        if not isinstance(args, tuple):
            args = (args,)
        self.set(value, *args)

    def _walk(self, obj, path):
        for segment in path:
            obj = obj[segment]
        return obj

    def get(self, *args, default=_SENTINEL):
        try:
            return _walk(_CONFIG_DATA, args)
        except LookupError:
            if default is _SENTINEL:
                raise LookupError(f"cannot walk path; {args}") from None
            else:
                return default

    def set(self, value, *args):
        *args, segment = args
        try:
            node = _walk(_CONFIG_DATA, args)
            node[segment] = value
        except LookupError:
            raise LookupError(f"cannot set path; {args}") from None
```

Comment: I guess I was a bit too caught up in last semesters functional programming lecture when opting for `reduce`. Although I enjoyed its conciseness, I do agree it harms readability. Thank you for the comprehensive suggestions. I will take a closer look at `pathlib` as well as your suggestions regarding the general approach.

Comment: @riskypenguin wrt `pathlib` [the very last section of the docs will likely be very helpful](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module). Yeah different languages have different idioms. A Haskell programmer would look favourably on code which uses `reduce`. A C# programmer would use the `tryGet` pattern  here. A good course will expose you to many common patterns, but not all patterns are good in every language.